# Why this output string to number?

Tags: c

I have a Question about the strcmp function in c. As Homework we do some comparissions about strings. But one thing is not clear, we have to compare numbers with this function. I know that there are other comparing methods to compare numbers, but our prof use it this way.

When I used the function like this:

```
char string1[] = "1";
char string2[] = "2"

printf("Compare between str1 and str2: %d, %d", strcmp(string1, string2));
```

-> Output:

```
Compare between str1 and str2: 1
```

Which would mean that the string1 is bigger.

I have then printf with just the variables:

```
printf("string1 %d", string1);  //output: 6356750
printf("string2 %d", string2);  //output: 6356748
```

Why are there such numbers? And what does this numbers mean?

I was thinking that the numbers in the string array are representing the ASCII Code but I think i am wrong.

Comment: Your title and what you say the question is about (in the first sentence) is totally misleading. You don't ask anything about `strcmp` at all. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I am o sorry, please apologize. Of course I was meaning:
printf("Compare between str1 and str2: %d, %d", strcmp(string1, string2));

Comment: I have updatet my question

Comment: `printf("Compare between str1 and str2: %d, %d", strcmp(string1, string2))`: this is wrong, yourt format string has two `%d`s, but you provide only one argument (`strcmp(string1, string2)`). Your compiler probably warned you about this.

Answer (score 5):

Please compile with full warnings! Always read those warnings carefully!

The compiler should have told you that your format string is wrong.

The % arguments in printf describe the type of the variable you are supplying. They don't provide any "free" type conversion, only formatting, so as you have strings, you need to use `%s`

What the compiler is trying to do instead is look at the pointer to your string and render that pointer value as an integer, but in fact it can't even do that properly if the size of integers is not the same as the size of pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the strings contain numbers, they are still ***strings***, and you need to print them using the `"%s"` format:

```
printf("Compare between str1 and str2: %s, %s", string1, string2);
//                                     ^^  ^^
// Note the format specifier being different
```

As for the "numbers" that are printed, remember that arrays decay to pointers to their first element. It's the decimal value of those pointers you're printing.

It should be noted that using mismatching format specifier and argument (like using `"%d"` to print a string) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

If you want to use *actual* numbers, and compare them with e.g. `<` or `>`, then you should have a numeric type instead, as in

```
int number1 = 1;
int number2 = 2;
```

Then you can print them with the `"%d"` format specifier, as it expects an argument of type `int`:

```
printf("Compare between number1 and number2: %d, %d", number1, number2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Compare between str1 and str2: %d, %d", string1, string2);
```

In that way you print address in memory of string1 and string2, in stack because this is fixed size array

To print string use `%s`:

```
printf("Compare between str1 and str2: %s, %s", string1, string2);
```

But this strings MUST be terminate by null ('\0') or function will read in memory until find cell with value 0.

To find ASCII code of CHAR (not whole string) use this:

```
printf("first char of str1: %c = %d", string1[0], (int)string1[0]);
```